# Index not defined in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the error I receive:

```
 "error" : "Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"release/date\", for path \"/north_america\", to the rules"
```

And this is the structure of my firebase data:

[image]

And my added rules don't seem to work, any help?

[image]

Comment: I'm in python..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating your database rules again with the index another level down.

```
"likes": {
  "north_america": {
    "$someid": {
      "release": {
        ".indexOn": ["date"]
      }
    }
 }
```

Also you should be able to wildcard out `north_america` so it works globally.

Comment: Thank you, but what does wildcard mean?

Comment: Wildcard, so it matches everything on that level. `$someid` is a wild card. You could change `north_america` to `$someCountry`.